# Is this sql command I wrote going to join these tables as desired?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, sql-view

**Problem**

I want to join two tables into one table. I have simplified the problem I am dealing at work considerably, but this is the basic idea.

Table 1

```
ID Value 
1  0 
2  0 
3  0
4  1
5  1
6  0
7  -1 
8  -1 
9  1 
10 0
```

Now we have table 2

```
ID Value 
1  -1 
2  -1 
3  -1 
10  1
```

I want to join table1 and table 2 so that I get the following:

```
ID Value 
1  -1 
2  -1 
3  -1 
4  1 
5  1
6  0 
7 -1 
8 -1 
9  1
10 1
```

**Attempt**

My first attempt was very stupid and wasted a lot of my time since the database is large. It went something like this:

```
SELECT ID, 
       CASE WHEN Table1.ID = Table2.ID THEN Table2.ID ELSE Table1.ID 
FROM Table1, Table2
```

Well, that was an honest mistake, but I still felt pretty n00b doing it. I felt like this when I did [it](http://gifs.gifbin.com/1239023890_showoff-touchdown-fail.gif).

I am thinking the following will solve my problem, but I am not that confident. Can someone please comment and let me know if I am on the right path?

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Value
INNER JOIN B 
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

I feel I am so very close, but would appreciate any kind assistance. I am going to go ahead and try this, but not sure if I am maintaining data integrity. I will be more then happy to contribute rep to anyone willing to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select t1.id, coalesce(t2.value, t1.value) as value
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Glad you gave the terminology. I found this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Thank you very much. This fixed the issue like a charm and taught me something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ID, 
       CASE 
         WHEN A.Value=0 AND A.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM #TAB2 )THEN B.Value  
         ELSE A.Value
       END VALUE
FROM #TAB1 A
LEFT JOIN #TAB2 B 
ON A.ID = B.ID
```